# Rails 4 and omniauth-facebook log in show blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I try to do log in through facebook and use the following manual:
http://tech.pro/tutorial/1430/ruby-on-rails-4-authentication-with-facebook-and-omniauth

When i try to go to **localhost:3000/auth/facebook**, there is only blank white page with this url:

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=&display=popup&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday%2Cread_stream&state=2e2af11c32ce8fcdd2d7106ac08a7655ce4dc50c2ae5b188

The same problem with heroku http://auth-sample.herokuapp.com/auth/facebook

Don't have any idea what to do!..

Use RAILS 4

config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, '1498472207038474', 'c6e381fb3eafcac5bdf9c335013d8677'
end
```

Comment: Did you configure your Facebook Application to allow logins from your domains (localhost for example)?

Comment: Also, you should NEVER EVER AT ALL add your Application id and SECRET publicly! you should change the secret at once!

Comment: @TamerShlash it's a sample application, so i decided not to hide them) the only settings, that i've done: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44046136/screen.JPG

Comment: Funny fact, link provided returns 500 from Facebook. OP, you're great. You broke Facebook :D

Comment: @MichalSzyndel lol) meanwhile, i've changed my secret app id and domain from localhost to the heroku's one. still see blank white page, ande all my friends see the same...

Comment: Maybe make sure that all params you pass are valid, 500 from Facebook never happened to me

Comment: @MichalSzyndel what params should i check? and how did you find out number of error?

Comment: By opening console in browser?

Comment: did you ever get a fix for this?  I'm running into same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this error as well and this is how I fixed it:

On developers.facebook.com, go to your App settings and click on "Add Platform" and then click on "Website". In the form that is then generated, type in

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

under "Site URL".

This made it work for me.

Note: I was only able to add one website URL to this platform list, so when I deploy, I'll probably have to change the URL.